# Deploy order in Mobicents JAIN SLEE

Tags: java, jboss5.x, jain-slee

I`m trying to launch Mobicents USSD Gateway. Right now the problem is following:
Jboss is trying to deploy module before he deploys its dependencies hence returning the error:

```
SLEE DUs not deployed, due to missing dependencies:
file:/mobicents-jainslee-2.7.0.FINAL-jboss-5.1.0.GA/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/mobicents-ussd-gateway/services-DU-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/
    Missing Dependencies:
        EventTypeID[name=ss7.map.DIALOG_REQUEST,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
        EventTypeID[name=ss7.map.DIALOG_DELIMITER,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
        EventTypeID[name=ss7.map.REJECT_COMPONENT,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
        EventTypeID[name=ss7.map.DIALOG_PROVIDERABORT,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
        ResourceAdaptorTypeID[name=MAPResourceAdaptorType,vendor=org.mobicents,version=2.0]
        EventTypeID[name=ss7.map.service.suplementary.PROCESS_UNSTRUCTURED_SS_REQUEST,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
        EventTypeID[name=ss7.map.DIALOG_TIMEOUT,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
        EventTypeID[name=ss7.map.DIALOG_REJECT,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
        EventTypeID[name=ss7.map.DIALOG_CLOSE,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
        EventTypeID[name=ss7.map.service.suplementary.UNSTRUCTURED_SS_RESPONSE,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
        LibraryID[name=library-map,vendor=library-map,version=2.0]
        EventTypeID[name=ss7.map.DIALOG_NOTICE,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
        EventTypeID[name=ss7.map.ERROR_COMPONENT,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
        EventTypeID[name=ss7.map.DIALOG_USERABORT,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
        EventTypeID[name=ss7.map.INVOKE_TIMEOUT,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
        EventTypeID[name=ss7.map.DIALOG_ACCEPT,vendor=org.mobicents,version=1.0]
        MAPRA
```

I`ve tried to set up dependencies to deployment unit services-DU-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar via jboss-deployement-structure.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="mobicents-slee-ra-jdbc-DU-1.0.0.FINAL.jar" />
      <module name="mobicents-slee-ra-map-du-2.8.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But this time he continues to try to install services-DU first, then reports missing dependencies, then succussfully installs dependencies, then tries to install services-DU again and throws exception:

```
2014-12-05 07:19:24,826 ERROR [org.mobicents.slee.container.deployment.jboss.DeploymentManager] (main) Failure invoking 'InstallDeployableUnitAction[file:/mobicents-jainslee-2.7.0.FINAL-jboss-5.1.0.GA/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/mobicents-ussd-gateway/services-DU-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/]
javax.slee.management.DeploymentException: Failure encountered during deploy process.
    at org.mobicents.slee.container.management.jmx.DeploymentMBeanImpl.install(DeploymentMBeanImpl.java:340)
    at org.mobicents.slee.container.deployment.jboss.action.InstallDeployableUnitAction.invoke(InstallDeployableUnitAction.java:41)
    at org.mobicents.slee.container.deployment.jboss.DeploymentManager.sciAction(DeploymentManager.java:316)
    at org.mobicents.slee.container.deployment.jboss.DeploymentManager.installDeployableUnit(DeploymentManager.java:181)
    at org.mobicents.slee.container.deployment.jboss.SLEESubDeployer.start(SLEESubDeployer.java:281)
```

I suppose it is a deploy order problem, but maybe I`m wrong and it is somethinf different. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be a real answer... but someone may find it useful.

I'm having exactly the same problem with those jBoss deployment logs.
I don't know how to solve it, but at least in my case, jBoss continue logging messages and finally it starts the UssdGateway.
Here there are some logs after those errors:

> 11:21:26,288 INFO  [UssdPropertiesManagement] (main) Loading USSD
>   Properties from
>   /home/ericsson/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/data/UssdManagement_ussdproperties.xml
>   11:21:26,295 INFO  [ShortCodeRoutingRuleManagement] (main) Loading
>   short code routig rule configuration from
>   /home/ericsson/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/data/UssdManagement_scroutingrule.xml
>   11:21:26,295 WARN  [ShortCodeRoutingRuleManagement] (main) Failed to
>   load the short code routig rule configuration file. 
>   /home/ericsson/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/data/UssdManagement_scroutingrule.xml
>   (No such file or directory) 11:21:26,302 INFO  [UssdManagement] (main)
>   Started UssdManagement 11:21:26,332 INFO  [ShellServer] (main)
>   Starting SS7 management shell environment 11:21:26,350 INFO 
>   [ShellServer] (main) ShellExecutor listening at /127.0.0.1:3435
>   11:21:26,510 INFO  [Http11Protocol] (main) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on
>   http-127.0.0.1-8080 11:21:26,549 INFO  [AjpProtocol] (main) Starting
>   Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009 11:21:26,566 INFO  [ServerImpl]
>   (main) JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA
>   date=200905221634)] Started in 1m:7s:690ms

And the gateway is funtional, because I was able to test it with the SS7 simulator, and the TestServlet was instanciated. In fact, I was able to test it with a real HLR, so it kind of works.
Now we have to code some developments on top of it...

For that error, and what can imply... I still do not have an answer.
Anyway, if I finally guess how to fix it, I will update this text.

Just a final comment...
To build this mobicents solution, it was a real pain.
The original instructions in [DeployUSSDGWFromTrunk](https://code.google.com/p/ussdgateway/wiki/DeployUSSDGWFromTrunk) **fail.**
I wasn't able to make it run, and it took us (a mate and me) about a week to make it compile and run, reading many google groups posts, and changing **random stuff** through the pom's.

Finally we got it running, but I still have that feeling that it is not a very good development base.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm already solved my problem, unfortunatly I'm already do not remember how. Sorry, can't vote up, not enough rep.